# Permissions From Other Application in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to use another third party application into my application. Basically using some of the services from third party app. But these services need custom permissions defined in the third party application. So I have added those permission in my applications manifest file.

Suppose if my application is installed before installing the third party application then it won't get those permissions and so if I try to access the services from third party app, I am getting Security exception.

Is there a way to ask for permissions again or any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a known limitation of custom permissions. Even if both apps where yours, the one that defines the custom permission needs to be installed first, otherwise you will get an exception. If you control both apps, you need to define it in both apps. Otherwise, there is really no workaround: a permission needs to be know to the system to be granted.

BTW, you *can* use a third-party permission, as long as it is not a signature permission, requiring your app to be signed with the same key.

Answer (score 3):

The permissions you request in your manifest are the permissions your app will receive regardless of when it is installed. Period. The permissions granted to another application are accessible by that application only. If there is a permission you need to use, it should be in your manifest. If it is there, permission will be requested from the user upon installation.